# RESTKit: Detect attribute changes in fetched Objects

Tags: core-data, restkit-0.20

iOS 7, RESTKit 0.20.X

I'm using the following code to compare local Core Data objects with the new and modified fetched objects to determine what all values of attributes have changed.  I have transient properties that end with `"M"` for modified.  i.e. actual attribute: `startDate` and transient: `startDateM`.  I loop through the array of fetched objects and if the values of attributes have changed, I mark the transient property.

The results are intermittent.  At times, the loop marks the correct attributes that have changed; however, often the loop marks attribute that hasn't been modified as modified, or never detects some or any of the attributes that have been modified.     I can see Charles log and have access to the Database to know for a FACT what all attributes were modified.

```
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
operation.managedObjectContext = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
operation.managedObjectCache = appDelegate.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
operation.savesToPersistentStore = NO;

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    NSSet *updatedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext updatedObjects];
    NSArray *_updatedObjects = updatedObjects.allObjects;

    for (int i = 0; i<_updatedObjects.count; i++)
    {
        if ([[_updatedObjects objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[Invite class]])
        {
            Invite *invite = [_updatedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *changedValues = [invite changedValues];
            NSArray *allKeys = [changedValues allKeys];

            invite.startDateM = [allKeys containsObject:@"startDate"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            invite.commentM = [allKeys containsObject:@"comment"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            invite.locationM = [allKeys containsObject:@"location"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

        }
        else if ([[_updatedObjects objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[Activity class]])
        {
            Activity *activity = [_updatedObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            NSDictionary *changedValues = [activity changedValues];
            NSArray *allKeys = [changedValues allKeys];

            activity.customDataM = [allKeys containsObject:@"customData"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            activity.latitudeM = [allKeys containsObject:@"latitude"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            activity.locationNameM = [allKeys containsObject:@"locationName"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            activity.longitudeM = [allKeys containsObject:@"longitude"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            activity.startTimeM = [allKeys containsObject:@"startTime"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            activity.activityStatusM = [allKeys containsObject:@"activityStatus"] ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        }
    }
    NSError *error;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error])
    {
        NSLog (@"******* INBOX OBJECTS SAVED AFTER DETECTING CHANGES**********");
    }

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];

[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  What's the alternative way/best practice to detect attribute changes in each object?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is your actual goal? Can you use custom accessor methods / KVO?

Comment: Why:  UserA POSTs an object.  UserB on another device modifies the object and PUTs.  UserA GET's the modified object. I need to show UserB what all attribute in the object were changed by UserA.  I have never used custom accessor methods / KVO.  Would that be a better approach? Can you please elaborate on that with some code sample?  Thanks.

Comment: "I need to show UserB what all attribute in the object were changed by UserA"...UserB of course has the original that was POSTed in his local database that will be used to compare with the new GET object.

Comment: Well, the code you have looks ok. Without seeing source data and a log of what updates the context thinks it has it's hard to say why it might not work. Particularly if you can't see any patterns. Otherwise it could be some error in your mapping meaning that some keys aren't processed.

Comment: Should I try KVO?  does that go into the model (NSManagedObject subclass) or inside `operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess...` block? Any examples?